# How to view or generate a selector string for any Ext JS component?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to come up with a selector string for a component. It would really be handy if there was a method that would just give this to me. Something like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.getSelector(component)
```

That would return me the fully qualified selector string for that component such that

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query(Ext.ComponentQuery.getSelector(component)) === component
```

I have not yet found a library method to obtain selector strings from component objects.

Edit: The question is not super awesome. Say you have a reference Ext JS component (button, field, etc...) nested deep in a hierarchy of containers, panels, grids, toolbars, which were all dynamically (programatically generated in an app) There is a likely an algorithm to generate a selector for that component up the ancestors of the component. So using the parent objects the component up the line back to the root object of the entire application viewport. I understand there is more than one way to select a specific component with the expressive syntax, I don't care about all the ways, just any way.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  As Evan Trimboli pointed out, what you're asking does not make sense.

Comment: This tool http://selectorgadget.com/ is a handy workaround for doing what I was trying to accomplish with an API method, just click the component on the screen to get the CSS selector string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ExtJs framework does not exists method which returns component selector.

However you can get id of component which have to be unique in your whole application and then use it in the selector. Each component implement [`getId()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getId) method which returns auto-generated unique id or id which you define in config when you create component.

```
var id = component.getId();
```

Then you can get component by its id:

```
Ext.getCmp(id);
```

or by id selector:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#' + id)[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

No such method exists. It's like asking "Is there a method to get the CSS selector for an element?". The answer is no, because you can select an element in a number of different ways.

To give a few examples, you can grab a component via:

- An id `#foo`
- An xtype `toolbar`
- A hierarchy selector `panel > container`
- An attribute `[action=foo]`

Or any combination of the above.